# PouchDB: Return query() result object

Tags: javascript, database, function, object, pouchdb

So I have this working PouchDB query which prints out the result into the console:

```
getActiveProjects();

function getActiveProjects() {
    function map_allActivePrj(doc) {emit(doc.projectStatus);}

    db.query(map_allActivePrj, {
        key          : '1',
        include_docs : true
    }).then(function (result) {
        // handle result
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, 4));          
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // handle errors
    });
}
```

Now I would like to call this function from an other function and return the result. I was not able to do that. I am aware that result is in the scope of the query.

Putting a "return" in front of "db.query" returns an empty object if I print it out with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(getActiveProjects()));
```

I'm not sure if this is a good Idea to make this function. Should I rather write my code inside the "//handle result" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a synchronous value from an asynchronous function. Instead, you can use a callback:

```
function getActiveProjects(cb) {
  ...
  }).then(function(result) {
    // do stuff
    cb(result);
  }).catch(...
}

getActiveProjects(function(result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Or return a promise and use that to retrieve the value:

```
function getActiveProjects() {
  ...
  return db.query(map_allActivePrj, {
    key: '1',
    include_docs: true
  }).then(function(result) {
    // do stuff
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  }).catch( ...
}

getActiveProjects().then(function(result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I'll try it right now. I was assuming that there is a problem with asynchronous running of code.